# Curves on the projective plane

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

I have two little questions, I'm learning this, and I'm not accustomed yet )=. The questions are so simple. First define on $$
R^3  - \left\{ {\left( {0,0,0} \right)} \right\}
$$
the topology given by the relation $$
\left( {x,y,z} \right) \sim \left( {tx,ty,tz} \right)
$$
call this new space $$
P^2 _R 
$$
Given an homogeneous polynomial $ F(x,y,z) $ over $R$. Then define $$
C = \left\{ {\left[ {x,y,z} \right] \in P^2 _R /F\left( {x,y,z} \right) = 0} \right\}
$$
I want to prove that $C$ is closed. I have no idea, clearly if the set was the set $$
D = \left\{ {\left( {x,y,z} \right) \in R^3 /F\left( {x,y,z} \right) = 0} \right\}
$$
being the preimage of zero, would be closed, by intuition I guess you should use that and something else but I do not know. T_T
Excuse me for these questions, but still can not get used to this.
And also prove that if $ F(x,y,z ) = ax+by+cz $ then two curves of this kind of function, always intersect, and only in one point.
Sorry for ask this simple question. But I want to see some examples. Thanks

Comment: Dear Daniel, Thinking about $D$ is a good start.  Now, what does it mean for a subset of a quotient, equipped with the quotient topology, to be closed?  Regards,

Comment: Dear Matt, I thought they removed all salutations, like Dear, from MSE? Hmm. I tried it here, and we see the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going up to $\mathbf R^3 \setminus \{0\}$ and $\mathbf R^3$ is the right thing to do. I presume that your definition of a quotient map is a a map $f\colon X \to Y$ of topological spaces such that $U \subset Y$ is open if and only if $f^{-1}(U)$ is open. But it is equivalent to require that $A \subset Y$ be closed if and only if $f^{-1}(A)$ is closed. (Check this!)

So I would try to think of the relationship between $C$ and $D \setminus \{0\} \subset \mathbf R^3 \setminus \{0\}$.

This advice also applies to your particular example. In $\mathbf R^3$, for $a, b, c$ not all zero, the zero set of $ax + by + cz$ is a two-dimensional vector subspace. If you have two distinct subspaces like this, what is their intersection? In particular, what dimension will the intersection have? This is just a problem in linear algebra.

Comment: Oh right, Thanks Matt, will be closed iff $$
p^{ - 1} \left( A \right)
$$  is closed, in this case, $$
p^{ - 1} \left( C \right) = D
$$
so it´s done O=

Comment: @Daniel Careful! It's $D$ less the origin.

Comment: O= Thanks !! and what did you said about subspaces? you are referring to the second question? sorry for ask xD

Comment: @Daniel Well, I wasn't very clear. Better now?

Comment: Yes you are right, they meet on a line through the origin, and that line on the proyective plane it´s one point. I was afraid , but I exagerated . Thanks